# How to create a non-linear slider in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, material-design

I want to add a slider to define the search radius in a map. When the radius is small, each meter counts, so the slider should allow for fine-grained changes. When the radius gets larger, the difference between, say, 5 and 6 km is minimal, so no need to spend many pixels with fine-grained control.

This is but an example out of many where non-linear sliders are useful ([this page details usability issues related to linear scales](https://baymard.com/blog/slider-interfaces)), but I couldn't find any references in [Material](https://material.io/design/components/sliders.html) or [Flutter sliders](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Slider-class.html). Which is a pity, since they already have discrete sliders; the only missing part is to accept a *list of values* instead of a single step increment, and it's done!

Here's an example of a non-linear slider that would be vaguely similar to what I seek (taken from [UI Movement](https://uimovement.com/design/change-plan/)):

[image: Example of a non-linear slider]

Did I miss something? Is there a way to quickly implement this in Android/Flutter, or do I need to make an entirely custom component for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement similar functionality by having a list of possible values, then using a slider to *index* an element in the list.

```dart
class ListSlider extends State{

  List<String> items = ['one','two','four','eight'];
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  setSelected(int value) {
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = value;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(items[selectedIndex]),
        Slider(
          min: 0,
          max: items.length -1,
          divisions: items.length -1
          onChanged: (double value) => setSelected(value.round())
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

Another way that might be interesting for numbers specifically, is to use a Slider with a range of (0.0, 1.0), then transform the output of the slider by a quadratic Animation Curve.